# How to get the name of an Attribute from an Entity

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following entity class:

```
public class Conversation { 
    private String id;
    private String ownerId;
    private Long creationDate;

    public Conversation(String id, String ownerId, Long creationDate){
        this.id = id;
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }
}
```

On other submodule through an external service, on each insertion, I recive a map of the following entities:

```
public class AttributeValue {
    private Sring s; //string attribute
    private String n; //number attribute

    public String getS() {
        return this.s;
    }

    public String getN() {
        return this.n;
    }

    public AttributeValue(String s, String n){
        this.s = s;
        this.n = n;
    }
}

//Example if I insert this conversation: new Conversation("1", "2", 1623221757971)
// I recive this map:
Map<String, AttributeValue> insertStream = Map.ofEntries(
    entry("id", new AttributeValue("1", null)),
    entry("ownerId", new AttributeValue("2", null)),
    entry("creationDate", new AttributeValue(null, "1623221757971"))
);
```

To read the ownerId field from the map, I have to do this:

```
String ownerId = insertStream.get("ownerId").getS();
```

My question is, instead of have to write: insertStream.get("ownerId"), exists any way through Reflection to read the name of the field from the entity (Conversation.ownerId)?
This is because we want to mantain the submodule and If we make a change on the entitity, for example change ownerId for ownerIdentifier, the submodule shows a compilation error or is changed automatically.

Comment: What’s the point of having two fields, `n` and `s`,  in `AttributeValue` when they still have a `String` type? With this design, the `AttributeValue` class makes the programming more complicated, compared to using just a `Map<String, String>`, with no benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? `Field#getName()`
Example code:

```
Field[] conversationFields = Conversation.class.getDeclaredFields();
String field0Name = conversationFields[0].getName();
```

Depending on the JVM used, `field0Name` can be `"id"`. You can also use `Class#getFields()`, this method includes all `Field`s that are accessible in this class (super class's fields).

---

Another option (not using reflection) would be to refactor your code.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Conversation {
    public static String[] names = {
        "id", "ownerId", "creationDate"
    };
    private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    public Conversation(Object... data) {
        if(data.length!=names.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You need to pass "+names.length+" arguments!");
        for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
            data.put(names[i],data[i]);
    }

    public Map<String,Object> getData() { return data; }

    // You can pass "id"/"ownerId" or names[0]/names[1]
    public String getString(String key) {
        return (String)data.get(key);
    }

    // You can pass "creationDate" or names[2]
    public long getLong(String key) {
        return (long)data.get(key);
    }
}
```

You could then create `Conversation` Objects like before:

```
Conversation c = new Conversation("myId","myOwnerId",123456789L);
```

You could also add `public static String` fields like `ID="id"`, but changing the value of a field will never change the field's name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will mark it as resolved if there is no other way to obtain the name than relying on the position of the field

Comment: @kevinLema What kind of generic way would you like ro use instead? If you don't want to specify the name if the fields explicitly, how do you want to obtain the name then? (What kind of signature should such a methkd have?)

Comment: I was expecting to acces the field name using their variable name, example:
`String ownerId = insertStream.get(Conversation.ownerId).getS();`

And if I change the name ownerId for senderId, then:
`String ownerId = insertStream.get(Conversation.senderId).getS();`

Comment: @kevinLema you didn’t name the purpose of getting the value from the map this way instead of getting the `ownerId` from a `Conversation` instance, as that class declares the field. The only useful purpose I know of, is to convert from the map to a `Conversation` instance which can be achieved by using the very `Field` whose `getName()` you used for looking up the map for setting the value as well. When doing that of all fields returned by `getDeclaredFields()` you are *not* depending on the order, as it doesn’t matter in which order you process them when you process all fields.